# Exceptions to rule that steering wheel corresponds to road lane?

Tags: transit

To help internationalize a dashboard app, I'm writing a small API that takes an ISO 3166 country code and returns which side of the vehicle the driver typically sits on.  (Of course there may be oddball imported vehicles in any country; those will have to be treated specially.)

[This page](http://www.worldstandards.eu/cars/list-of-left-driving-countries/) says (emphasis added):

> *Almost always*, in countries where one drives on the right-hand side of the road, the cars are built so that the driver sits on the left-hand side of the car. Conversely, driving on the left-hand side of the road *usually* implies that the driver’s seat is on the right-hand side of the car.

I find similar hedged statements elsewhere.  My question is, **which countries are the exceptions to this rule?**

Comment: Is the dashboard app the only client of the API? Will the user have to enter the country code manually, or is this just to set a default that will be correct 99% of the time? My perspective is that it would be simplest to have a one-time prompt asking, "Which side of the car is the driver's seat?" and go from there.

Answer (score 2):

Countries usually change the side of the road they are dominated by imported cars built for the other side.

So countries about to or who recently changed will have a mix nearer 50% than 100%. In these locales wrong sidedness will not be oddball cases. There aren't that many but if you are building an API you will be serving people who care about these cases. Samoa was the most recent (the first for three decades).